# How to update records from multiple tables sharing one field with one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database for a forum-like website. It has a 'users' table, which is linked to other tables ('posts', 'votes', etc.) with foreign keys.

I am implementing a feature for merging two users into one of them, which requires relinking all tables. So I'd like to construct a query like this (in this case, user_id=1 is the id of the untouched user and user_id=2 is the id of the user that is being merged into first one):

```
UPDATE posts, votes ... SET user_id=1 WHERE user_id=2
```

I am, naturally, getting an error: "Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous".

My question is: how can I achieve the required result with just one query? (If possible)

EDIT: Actual number of tables is about 6, so if you could take that into account in your answer, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try set your value in [Table_Name].Column format.

Instead of using user_id try using posts.user_id

Comment: So, it's supposed to be 'UPDATE posts, votes SET posts.user_id=1, votes.user_id=1 WHERE posts.user_id=2, votes.user_id=2'? I'm not sure I've got valid MySQL code here.

Comment: @exizt: where posts.user_id = votes.user_id and posts.user_id = 2

Comment: But what if there are actually about 6 tables? (sorry I haven't mentioned that in the original post).

Comment: @exist This answer demonstrates why you can't update multiple tables in a single UPDATE statement. :)

Comment: I don't really fully get it, but thank you for your input regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do.

```
    UPDATE posts SET user_id=votes.user_id
    FROM posts INNER JOIN votes ON posts.something=votes.something
```

Perform the updates in sequence if more than one table needs to be updated.